# SwiftUI: Array with UserDefault- items keep coming back after removal

Tags: swiftui, userdefaults

I am trying to make a list where the user can remove items. But the items keep coming back after I close the app.  I can sense that it is because the List/ForEach keeps reading the original value of array, not the saved array. But I don't know how to make it do so. All the tutorials I could find on UserDefault talks about encoding the item in JSON then save it. The ones that are actually about using UserDefault on an array are too simplistic.

Any help is much appriciated. Thank you

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var array: [String] = ["one", "two", "three"]
    
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(array, id: \.self) { item in
                Text("\(item)")
            }
            .onDelete(perform: delete)
            
            Text("abc")
        }
    }
    
    func delete(offsets: IndexSet){
        array.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        userDefaults.set(array, forKey: "List1")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Use app storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this, if you really want to use `UserDefaults` directly. Otherwise use `AppStorage`, see:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/appstorage

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var array: [String] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(array, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }.onDelete(perform: delete)
            Text("abc")
        }
        .onAppear {
            if let results = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "List1") as? [String] {
                array = results
            } else {
                array = ["one", "two", "three"]
            }
        }
    }
    
    func delete(offsets: IndexSet){
        array.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(array, forKey: "List1")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I used Userdefault in my project not because I don't like appstorage but I have always thought appstorage is not applicable to Array.  I remember reading it somewhere appstorage only works for simple data type.  I must be wrong.  Anyways, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Data should be kept in the model, while the view presents the data and responds to the change of the data.

```
import SwiftUI

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var array: [String] = []

    private struct Constants {
        static let defaultsKey = "List1"
    }

    init() {
        let array = restore()
        if let array = array, array.count > 0 {
            self.array = array
        } else {
            self.array = ["one", "two", "three"]
        }
    }

    func delete(offsets: IndexSet){
        array.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        store()
    }

    private func store() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(array, forKey: Constants.defaultsKey)
    }

    private func restore() -> Array<String>? {
        return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: Constants.defaultsKey) as? Array<String>
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    init(viewModel: ViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(viewModel.array, id: \.self) { item in
                Text("\(item)")
            }
            .onDelete(perform: delete)
            Text("abc")
        }
    }

    func delete(offsets: IndexSet){
        viewModel.delete(offsets: offsets)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(viewModel: ViewModel())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice.  I will keep in mind that the model and the view should be separate.  That said, you code is way out of my league.   I have no idea what these mean "private(set)", Array<String>. You leave me with a lot of food for thought.  Thank you so much.